# php Config file to external js file

Tags: php, json, external-js

please help me on how to implement this
How can i pass/access a config varible from my Config.php to an external Php'd JS file

in my Config.php

```
define('LIBS', 'http://localhost/libs/');
```

I'm doing this in my external js file

```
alert(<?php echo json_encode('LIBS');)
```

my other option would be, re-initialize a the php config variables, something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var jsLIBS= <?php echo json_encode('LIBS'); ?>
</script>
```

within my main php file and set it as global variables

thank you

Comment: within server u can refer js files wherever the file is located.

Answer (score 0):

why just not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var jsLIBS= '<?php echo LIBS; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: not sure if possible but i want to maintain just 1 config file

Comment: I just read "I'm doing this in my external js file" - you should have set this in your main html - before attaching your external script - then jsLIBS will be visible in this file too